# Cosmos DB Emulator on Mac with M2 Chip - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when using local IP

Tags: macos, azure-cosmosdb, parallels, azure-cosmosdb-emulator

I am trying to run the Cosmos DB Emulator on my Mac with an M2 chip. I followed the [official Microsoft documentation that suggests using Parallels to run Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator?tabs=ssl-netstd21) and then install the Cosmos DB Emulator on the virtual machine.

Following the guide, I executed the following command in the Windows environment:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /AllowNetworkAccess /Key=C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==
```

The emulator starts, and I can access it using `https://localhost:8081/_explorer/index.html` within the virtual machine. However, I am unable to access it from my Mac using the local IP address obtained via `ipconfig`. I keep getting an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error.

Upon investigating further with `netstat -a | findstr 8081`, I noticed that the emulator is listening on `127.0.0.1:8081`. I suspect this might be the reason I cannot connect using the local IP.

Here are some additional details:

- Parallels network settings: Running in "shared" mode.
- I attempted port forwarding using Parallels, but it didn't resolve the issue.
- I tried the "nofirewall" flag, deleted the contents of `%LOCALAPPDATA%\CosmosDBEmulator`, disabled the firewall, and added allow rules without success.

Steps I've taken so far:

1. Executed the emulator command in the Windows environment.
2. Checked `netstat` for listening addresses.
3. Tried port forwarding via Parallels.
4. Tried the "nofirewall" flag, deleted emulator contents, disabled firewall, and added allow rules.

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is the IP for `localhost`

Comment: Can you add a link to the "official Microsoft documentation" that you are following?

Comment: I have added the link to the original post, yes, I am aware that 127.0.0.1 is the IP for localhost, but when I try to use my local ip: `10.211.55.3` it will not let me connect.

Comment: The `Shared` network mode is explained in "[Network modes in Parallels Desktop for Mac](https://kb.parallels.com/4948)". Have you tried changing to `Bridged` mode? With `Shared` the VM is behind a virtual subnet which may be complicating things.

Comment: I tried using `Bridged`, sadly same result, maybe it's important to note when using `10.211.55.3` (so the VMs ip) inside of the VM I still get the `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`, both in `Bridged` and `Shared` mode.

Comment: You are using HTTPS. So you [imported the emulator TLS/SSL certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator?tabs=ssl-netstd21#macos-environment), correct?

Comment: Correct, I think the issue is just that the emulator is not listening on `0.0.0.0`, but I am not sure how I can force that.